# "find: rename: no such file or directory" when running `-exec rename` in find

Tags: command-line, rename

I am trying to rename files in src folder bitcoin/src by using:

```
find . -exec rename 's/bitcoin/altcoin/' {} ";"
```

also tried:

```
find ./ -type f -readable -writable -exec rename -e 's/bitcoin/altcoin/g' {} \;
```

and I got this:

```
find: ‘rename’: No such file or directory
```

I am trying to fork bitcoin to my own altcoin, using Ubuntu 18.04!

What's the problem and how can I fix it?